# Libgdx Keys.SPACE not returning true

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I'm writing a game with a very simple conditional in Android Studio (latest version)

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE)){//foo}
```

However, it never returns true, and foo is not happening. If I try `Keys.ENTER` it works, and I have also cleaned my project and restarted my computer, however, libgdx is still is not working correctly, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: From what package does `Keys` class come from? Because I see that it must be `Input.Keys.SPACE`. BTW, I just checked and your code works fine in my project (when I use `Input.Keys.SPACE`)

Comment: Check what is the KeyCode is when you press space, might give you a place to start investigating the issue. For space, it should be 62. See https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/constant-values.html#com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys.SPACE